# Angular test reactive form validation service method getting controls ourside the method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a validation service with different validation methods. Usually I send the control to the validation like this example:

```
dateTodayOrlater(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
   const selectedDate = new Date(control.value);
   if ("more stuff here") {
     return { dateTodayOrlater: true };
   }
   //"more stuff here"
   return null;
 }
```

and testing building new control with value:

```
it('should validate dateTodayOrlater with errors', () => {
    const control = new FormControl('2000-01-20');
    const res = service.dateTodayOrlater(control);
    expect(res).toEqual({ dateTodayOrlater: true });
  });
```

but now I have a validation that depends on another form controls like this:

```
dateRange(
  startDateControl: string,
  endDateControl: string
): ValidationErrors | null {
  return (controls: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const startControl = controls.get(startDateControl);
    const endControl = controls.get(endDateControl);
    const startVal = startControl?.value;
    const endVal = endControl?.value;
    if ("more stuff here") {
        return { dateRange: true };
    }
    //"more stuff here"
    return null;
  };
}
```

as

> startDateControl

and

> endDateControl

are both strings and inside the validation I get the controls from the form:

```
const startControl = controls.get(startDateControl); 
const endControl = controls.get(endDateControl);
```

how can i test or mock something for test this situation? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to pass a formGroup.

I am not 100% certain but I think something like this should work.

```
it('should do stuff', () => {
  const formGroup = new FormGroup({
    startDate: new FormControl('2000-01-20'),
    endDate: new FormControl('2000-12-20'),
  });
  // this method returns a function
  const func = service.dateRange('startDate', 'endDate');
  // call the function with the formGroup
  const result = func(formGroup);
  expect(result).toBe(....);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I don't understand very well your solution. How could I call the function with the formGroup? it seems that I can't, I have not formGroup like a param in any function inside the valdiations service. I don't know if I'm understanding you

Comment: Hello, I think your validator is called, it is returning a function. I think the solution I showed you, your validator is being called and stored in `func`. We later call `func` with the `formGroup` and see what the function that is being returned is giving us.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. The problem is that usin func I have this error: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'ValidationErrors' has no call signatures.

Comment: Interesting. I think what you should do is create a formGroup with the validators and then test the `form.errors` object has what you want it to have. Something like this: https://pashozator.medium.com/angular-validators-unit-testing-3a3ed9b4665b.

Comment: ok I will try with that, Thanks a lot